# Find the odd int - Ruby Nested Loop Error

Tags: ruby, nested-loops

I was doing this question on codewars: "Given an array, find the int that appears an odd number of times. There will always be only one integer that appears an odd number of times."

Code:

```
def find_it(seq)
  int = []
  for a in seq do
    count = 0
    for b in seq do
      if a == b
        count += 1
      end
    end
    if count % 2.0 != 0
      int << b
    end
  end      
  puts int.uniq[0].to_i
end
```

It was tested against a couple inputs, but the answers were wrong for these two arrays:

`find_it([1,1,2,-2,5,2,4,4,-1,-2,5])` - returns 5 instead of -1

`find_it([1,1,1,1,1,1,10,1,1,1,1])` - returns 1 instead of 10

What went wrong with my code?

Comment: You want `int << a`, not `int << b`.

Comment: There are many ways your code could be improved and made more Ruby-like. I suggest that after making the correction I mentioned you post it at SO's sister-site, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There your code will be critiqued and suggested improvements will be offered. That site requires working code; SO deals with broken code and algorithmic issues.

Comment: Just to give an idea of how Ruby is funny, using [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html), [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html) and [Enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator.html), you can get: `array.uniq.map { |e| {value: e, counts: array.count(e)} }.select{ |h| h[:counts].odd? }`

Comment: @iGian: A faster version, as iterated `count` is slower than it needs to be: `array.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |a, k| a[k] += 1; a }.select{ |k,v| v.odd? }.keys.first`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if count % 2.0 != 0
      int << b
    end
```

The problem you have here is that your pushing b instead of a into the integer array, so what's happening is that instead of the value that you counted being pushed in, your pushing in the last value of b which is the last value element in the array regardless as long as the condition that the counter is an odd number, although b and counter have nothing to do with each other. so to fix it you replace b with a so that it pushes in the value you are testing comparing with the other elements in the second loop

fix:

```
if count % 2.0 != 0
      int << a
    end
```

a similar yet simpler code that does a similar job except in a shorter and more understandable way is:

```
def find_it(seq)
  numberWithOddCount = 0
  seq.each do |currentElement|
    counter = 0
    seq.each { |elementToCompare| counter += 1 if currentElement == elementToCompare}
    numberWithOddCount = currentElement if counter % 2 != 0
  end
  numberWithOddCount
end
```

Just added a few tid-bits that you could also utilize to shorten and simplify code.

Happy Coding!

***Note:***

You could utilize built in ruby methods in creative ways to make the code do what you want in very few lines (or even one line) such as what @iGian did in the questions comments, but if your still new to ruby then its best to utilize those methods one by one when learning them otherwise you'll be confused. But if your willing to take the time now to learn them, I suggest you take his code and separate each method execution into its own line and output what each method had done to know what's doing what. and practice using each separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_it(seq)
  seq.group_by{|x| x}.select{|k, v| (v.count % 2.0 !=0)}.first[0]
end
```

The above code will take a sequence in an array. Here we are grouping by elements:

For example:

```
[1,1,2,-2,5,2,4,4,-1,-2,5].group_by{|x| x}
# => {1=>[1, 1], 2=>[2, 2], -2=>[-2, -2], 5=>[5, 5], 4=>[4, 4], -1=>[-1]}
```

after getting the above results, we are finding the whose elements count not odd with the select condition.

ex:

```
[1,1,2,-2,5,2,4,4,-1,-2,5].group_by{|x| x}.select{|k, v| (v.count % 2.0 !=0)}
```

we will get the results as `{-1=>[-1]}`

we are taking the key as result element.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. To further improve the usability of your answers, please try to not just add a bunch of code without any explanation though. Instead, please add some detail's about what exactly the code does, how it solves the given problem and how (and why) it is a more suitable solution than what OP originally attempted.

Comment: Thank you, for the comment, I have updated the explanation about code.

Answer (score 1):

@aimen_alt is right about your mistake

but let's decompose your problem.

First, you need to calculate the appearances of each number.
Second, you need to find the one with the odd count of the appearances.
Accordingly to the problem, there is only one such number, so you can return it right away.

You can go your way and do it in `O(N^2)` complexity by scanning your sequence for each item in the sequence (so `N` items in the sequence multiply by the size of the sequence `N` = `N*N`). You can do it linearly* by constructing a `Hash` and than you'll be able to get the key with odd value:

```
def find_it(seq)
  numbers = {}
  seq.each do |item|
    numbers[item] = numbers[item].to_i + 1
  end
  numbers.select{ |k,v| v.odd? }.first.first
end
```

to be more idiomatic you can use `group_by` to group the numbers themselves:

```
seq = [1, 2, 6, 1, 2]
seq.group_by{ |item| item }
#=> {1=>[1, 1], 2=>[2, 2], 6=>[6]}
```

You can see that each value is an Array, and you just need to get one with the odd amount of items:

```
seq = [1, 2, 6, 1, 2]
seq.group_by{ |item| item }.select{ |k, v| v.size.odd? }
#=> {6=>[6]}
```

And the last thing you would like to do is to get the value of the key:

```
seq.group_by{ |item| item }.select{ |k, v| v.size.odd? }.keys.first
```

So, the final solution would be

```
def find_it(seq)
  seq.group_by{ |item| item }
     .select{ |k, v| v.size.odd? }
     .keys
     .first
end
```

as @pascalbetz mentioned:

```
def find_it(seq)
  seq.group_by{ |item| item }
     .find{ |k, v| v.size.odd? }
     .first
end
```

Comment: Since there is only one entry with an odd size you could use `find` instead of `select` (abort the one and only entry with odd size is found)

Comment: I just timed it... almost no difference for my microbenchmark (it depends on the size of input and number of different entries in the array)

Comment: that's about `O(n/2)` over `O(n)` in the average case. And `O(1)` over `O(n)` in the best case, so absolutely legit.

Comment: FYI: This is one of the fastest variant for a 10_000 array so far...in my microbenchmark.

Comment: that's expected: we omit constructing Hash back and calling for `keys` :)

Answer (score 1):

What about this one

```
def find_it(seq)
  seq.reduce(:^)
end
```

^ -> this symbol is bitwise **XOR**.
reduce function is taking each value and doing whatever work assigned inside. In this case, it's taking each element and doing an XOR operation. the first element is doing XOR with zero and the next element doing XOR with the previous result and so on.

In this way, we found the odd element.

How XOR operation work

```
0 ^ 2 = 2
4 ^ 4 = 0
```

If you want to know more about XOR. kindly refer to [this](https://medium.com/@tonyjlum/xor-exclusive-or-in-ruby-and-a-bit-more-900e6aca8db).

Comment: This answer seems to nail the solution. Can you explain it a little bit?

Comment: Thank you, for the comment, I have updated the explanation about the code.

Comment: That's a great answer Sudo

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the detailed answers, I'm going over everyone's answers now. I'm new to Ruby, and I'm still in the process of learning the methods/rules of using them/Big O notation, so I much appreciated everyone's input. Codewar listed some top ranked solutions. This seems to be the fastest so far:

```
def find_it(seq)   
   seq.detect { |n| seq.count(n).odd? } 
end
```